# Coding a regexp in the names_pattern argument of pivot_longer for multiple variables differentiated by presence or absence of a prefix

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, reshape, tidyr

I have a dataset I need to pivot_longer() with two kinds of variables in its columns: quantity and proportion. Quantity is entered under the species name, and proportion is entered under P followed by the species name. Each row represents the data for an hour-long sampling period.

Here is a simplified version of the data I'm working with.
(EDIT: I added another column to the code, RH_percent, to help refine the regexp.)

[image: sample input data]

```
#code to recreate input data
sampledata <- read_csv("date,time,RH_percent,Cx_tarsalis,Ps_columb,PCx_tarsalis,PPs_columb
2020-07-20,19:00:00,0.25,3,4,0.03,0.04
2020-07-20,20:00:00,0.5,6,8,0.06,0.08
2020-07-20,21:00:00,0.75,9,12,0.09,0.12")
```

This is what I want my output to look like:
[image: sample output data]

```
#code to recreate desired output data
sampleoutput <- read_csv("date,time,RH_percent,species,quantity,P
         2020-07-20,19:00:00,0.25,Cx_tarsalis,3,0.03
         2020-07-20,19:00:00,0.25,Ps_columb,4,0.04
         2020-07-20,20:00:00,0.5,Cx_tarsalis,6,0.06
         2020-07-20,20:00:00,0.5,Ps_columb,8,0.08
         2020-07-20,21:00:00,0.75,Cx_tarsalis,9,0.09
         2020-07-20,21:00:00,0.75,Ps_columb,12,0.12")
```

I know the code will look something like this, and I know I need to specify a regexp in the names_pattern argument:

```
sampledata %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c(date,time),
                            names_to = c(".value","species"),
                            names_pattern = "")
```

I have been studying examples online, including the [Pivoting vignette](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html) and [Roger Peng's regexp videos on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvHjYOilOf8) but have not hit on the correct names_pattern to get the output I need.

A similar problem is solved in: [pivot_longer multiple variables of different kinds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63994970/pivot-longer-multiple-variables-of-different-kinds), but the way the variables are represented in the columns, and thus the pattern in the regexp, are substantially different from what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach with `rename`ing

1. Rename the columns 3 and 4 by adding a suffix `-quantity`
2. Rename the columns 5 and 6 by adding suffix `-P`
3. Use the `names_sep` as `-` and specify the `names_to` in the order `species`, `.value` in `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
sampledata %>%
    rename_with(~ str_c(., '-quantity'), 3:4) %>%
    rename_with(~ str_c(str_remove(., '^P'), '-P'), 5:6) %>%    
   pivot_longer(cols = -c(date,time),
                            names_to = c("species", ".value"),
                            names_sep = "-")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  date       time   species     quantity     P
  <date>     <time> <chr>          <dbl> <dbl>
1 2020-07-20 19:00  Cx_tarsalis        3  0.03
2 2020-07-20 19:00  Ps_columb          4  0.04
3 2020-07-20 20:00  Cx_tarsalis        6  0.06
4 2020-07-20 20:00  Ps_columb          8  0.08
5 2020-07-20 21:00  Cx_tarsalis        9  0.09
6 2020-07-20 21:00  Ps_columb         12  0.12
```

---

Or another approach is just to add a prefix where the column names have only two character before the `_` i.e. those are the quantity columns 'Q'.  Then, in the `names_pattern`, capture the first character (`(.)`) as the first capture group, then the rest of characters (`(.*)`) as second, which will denote for ".value" and "species" specified in `names_to`

```
sampledata %>%
     rename_with(~ str_c('Q', .), matches('^.._')) %>% 
     pivot_longer(cols = -c(date, time), 
        names_to = c(".value", "species"), names_pattern = "^(.)(.*)") %>% 
     rename(quantity = Q)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  date       time   species     quantity     P
  <date>     <time> <chr>          <dbl> <dbl>
1 2020-07-20 19:00  Cx_tarsalis        3  0.03
2 2020-07-20 19:00  Ps_columb          4  0.04
3 2020-07-20 20:00  Cx_tarsalis        6  0.06
4 2020-07-20 20:00  Ps_columb          8  0.08
5 2020-07-20 21:00  Cx_tarsalis        9  0.09
6 2020-07-20 21:00  Ps_columb         12  0.12
```

#### Update

With the OP's new dataset, use `ignore.case = FALSE` in `matches` as by default it is `TRUE`

```
sampledata %>%
     rename_with(~ str_c('Q', .), matches('^[A-Z][a-z]_[a-z]', 
       ignore.case = FALSE)) %>% 
     pivot_longer(cols = -c(date, time, RH_percent), 
        names_to = c(".value", "species"), names_pattern = "^(.)(.*)") %>% 
     rename(quantity = Q)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  date       time   RH_percent species     quantity     P
  <date>     <time>      <dbl> <chr>          <dbl> <dbl>
1 2020-07-20 19:00        0.25 Cx_tarsalis        3  0.03
2 2020-07-20 19:00        0.25 Ps_columb          4  0.04
3 2020-07-20 20:00        0.5  Cx_tarsalis        6  0.06
4 2020-07-20 20:00        0.5  Ps_columb          8  0.08
5 2020-07-20 21:00        0.75 Cx_tarsalis        9  0.09
6 2020-07-20 21:00        0.75 Ps_columb         12  0.12
```

Comment: The code worked on my sample data! But in my data set, rename_with affected two additional columns, RH_percent and hr_post_sunset. I tried to make it case sensitive by trying many variations on the regexp in matches(), such as matches('^([A-Z])([a-z])_')) -- but I was unable to change the result. Do you know how to make matches() specific for a capital letter followed by a lowercase letter followed by _?

Comment: Sorry, I did not include the other columns in the sample data because they would not have been affected by the names_pattern argument of pivot_longer. I did not expect a solution where a regexp would be applied to all the columns.