# Pivot Longer to Multiple Fields

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to pivot wide table to a long one and extract two columns for each numeric suffix.

The output needs to look like this. So the Responses and Response Categories need to follow the suffix of those fields.

I will be similar to [pivot_longer multiple variables of different kinds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63994970/pivot-longer-multiple-variables-of-different-kinds) but I'm not following how that works.

| ID | Response No | Response | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Hot | A |
| 1 | 2 | Very hot | C |
| 2 | 1 | Very hot | A |
| 2 | 2 | Cold | B |
| 3 | 1 | Cold | C |
| 3 | 2 | Luke Warm | B |
| 4 | 1 | Luke Warm | B |
| 4 | 2 | Tepid | A |

With the original table like this...

```
data <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4),
                   response1 = c("Hot", "Very hot", "Cold", "Luke Warm"),
                   response2 = c("Very hot", "Cold", "Luke Warm", "Tepid"),
                   reponseCategory1 = c("A", "A", "C", "B"),
                   reponseCategory2 = c("C", "B", "B", "A")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('response'),
               ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `names_pattern` to capture as group - `(\\D+)`- one or more non-digits, `(\\d+)` one or more digits

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(data, cols= -id, names_to = c(".value", "ResponseNo"), 
      names_pattern = "(\\D+)(\\d+)", names_prefix = "reponse")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 4
     id ResponseNo response  Category
  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>     <chr>   
1     1 1          Hot       A       
2     1 2          Very hot  C       
3     2 1          Very hot  A       
4     2 2          Cold      B       
5     3 1          Cold      C       
6     3 2          Luke Warm B       
7     4 1          Luke Warm B       
8     4 2          Tepid     A
```

---

If it was `response` instead of `reponse`

```
library(dplyr)
pivot_longer(data, cols= -id, names_to = c(".value", "ResponseNo"), 
      names_pattern = "(\\D+)(\\d+)") %>%
  rename(Category = responseCategory)
```

#### data

```
data <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4),
                   response1 = c("Hot", "Very hot", "Cold", "Luke Warm"),
                   response2 = c("Very hot", "Cold", "Luke Warm", "Tepid"),
                   reponseCategory1 = c("A", "A", "C", "B")
```

Comment: I seem to be getting Error in `build_longer_spec()`:
! If you supply multiple names in `names_to` you must also supply one of `names_sep` or `names_pattern`. even though names_pattern is there

Comment: @Chris I used `packageVersion('tidyr')#
[1] ‘1.2.0’` to run this code and it is working fine with your data example

Comment: @Chris I noticed that the Category columns had `reponse` is it is a typo? and you had `response` in the original data?

Comment: I think there there was 3 issues.  A different version of tidyr, my typo in reponse and the names_prefix = "reponse".  When the text in the prefix matches the text in all the fields, it introduces extra rows.  Once that is removed, it works as expected.  so thank you.  if you edit that, I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution in base R:

```r
reshape(data, dir = "long", varying = list(c(2:3), c(4:5)), 
        v.names = c("response", "Category"), timevar = "ResponseNo")

#>     id ResponseNo  response Category
#> 1.1  1          1       Hot        A
#> 2.1  2          1  Very hot        A
#> 3.1  3          1      Cold        C
#> 4.1  4          1 Luke Warm        B
#> 1.2  1          2  Very hot        C
#> 2.2  2          2      Cold        B
#> 3.2  3          2 Luke Warm        B
#> 4.2  4          2     Tepid        A
```